# PHP post submit not submitting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a button that is not submitting a form via php post request.
I don't understand why it's not producing the result when the button is pressed.

```
<?php  

    if ($_POST["submit"]){
        //$result="form submitted";
        $result='<div class="alert alert-success">form submitted</div>';
    }

?>
```

which is referenced from here within a html body:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg" value="Submit" />
```

here's the problem on a live site.
[the website](http://176.32.230.250/errorreporting.com/index.php)

Comment: Always prefer creating a working and editable example with such website as [JSFiddle](https://www.jsfiddle.net) rather than adding a link to your website or one you work for. And can you show us the whole form element please ?

Comment: here is a JSBin paste:
https://jsbin.com/wiqiwuxavi/edit?html

Comment: what are you doing with `$result`, it may have been defined but not used.

Comment: If that's your full code, then `$result` is never echoed. It's set, but never showed anywhere. `echo $result;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible that you just forgot to echo the result, like this:

```
 if ( isset( $_POST["submit"] )){
    //$result="form submitted";
    $result='<div class="alert alert-success">form submitted</div>';
    echo $result;
}
```